# Get all the procedures and functions which are created with compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When creating a procedure/function some are created with compilation errors;

```
Procedure created.
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
Procedure created.
Procedure created.
```

How to get the list of `procedure/ functions` which are created `compilation error` in `Oracle`?

Comment: What if just take a look at invalid procedures? `SELECT *
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE' AND status = 'INVALID'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query `SYS.USER_ERRORS`:

```
select * from SYS.USER_ERRORS where type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

If there is no guarantee that the user running those is the same user you are logged in with, then query `SYS.ALL_ERRORS`.

Answer (score 2):

replace owner with your schema

```
select * from all_objects
where status = 'INVALID'
and owner = 'SCOTT' ;
```

Comment: Won't that also show you objects that have been invalidated by dependencies but which will compile successfully when next referenced? Not just those with compilation errors.

Comment: Invalid means compilation errors, in current code or in dependencies. This is your responsibility as developer/DBA to follow, debug and correct it to get valid procedure/function without errors.

Comment: Invalid means it needs to be compiled, not that is has errored, or will error. e.g. if you have a procedure with a %type reference and you alter the column data type the dependency means the procedure will go invalid; but there is nothing in user_errors, and alter procedure compile (or just calling it) will take it back to valid. (I'm not disagreeing that something with compilation errors will be invalid; just that is not the only reason)

Comment: @AlexPoole I agree with you, however this still your responsibility as developer/DBA to follow, debug and correct

Comment: @AlexPoole some IDEs like pl/sql developer Helps to compile all invalid objects at one shot, I usually use it to quick fix Invalid objects, if invalid dependent recompiled successfully its new status become valid this will be enough. else this will required debugging to check errors by hand.

Comment: Yep, agree anything that stays invalid needs to be investigated of course. I do a similar thing with `dbms_utility.compile_schema(user)` -which can help when building multiple objects with dependencies, which could be what the OP is seeing, as it clears temporary problems. (Or in DBA mode at run `utlrp.sql`, but overkill here!).